# RTK Query - useQuery and useLazyQuery work independently

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

I have a form where users can update data. At the same time, an admin can update that same data.

In the user form I use useQuery. When the admin updates data, it sends a message through websockets to the user. The websocket hook on the user's side uses useLazyQuery to trigger it to update the user's form when an admin makes a change. However, useQuery and useLazyQuery seem to operate independently as far as I can tell even though they stem from the same builder. Both work perfectly fine independently.

The crux -> The isFetching is not triggered in useQuery when I trigger useLazyQuery.

How can I trigger useQuery to update the form data on the user's side when the websocket gets an update from the admin?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? If called with the same argument, those two will definitely share their result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you want to update the form data on the user's side by re-fetching the data from your API.

As described in the doc : https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior#re-fetching-on-demand-with-refetchinitiate you can use `refetch` in useQuery.

```
const { data, refetch } = useGetPostsQuery(5)
```